# Getting Input into separate array indexes in Python

Tags: python, arrays, input

I'm trying to make a program that will take an input in and put it into an `array` so that it can then be used later on in the program.

> How do you get the input into separate indexes (not sure that's the right word) in an array?

I've tried entering the input with commas but all it does is it counts the commas as part of the string and when I try to print the sequence[0:4](for example) it prints out the input counting the commas in giving me this:

```
#Code
sequence = [""]
sequence = input("Please enter a sequence:\n")
print(sequence[0:4])
```

This gives me this:

```
Please enter a sequence:
R,B,G,R,B,G #Input
R,B, #Output
```

I would like this to print out:

```
R,B,G,R
```

Is their any way of doing this and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you're slicing on string not on array, input by default gives you string by split we convert it into an array. And then join the element of those arrays.

Yes the way to do is :

```
sequence = input("Please enter a sequence:\n").split(',')
print(','.join(sequence[0:4]))
```

Comment: the first line is useless BTW

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre better now?

Comment: Shit! sorry, I blindly copied from the actual question.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for that. Sorry about how basic it was

Answer (score 0):

`input()` always returns a string. If you want to turn it into a list, do

```
sequence2 = sequence.split(',')
```

And if you want to print it in that exact format, do

```
print(",".join(sequence2[0:4])
```